# XSLT global variable to reuse text in an attribute specifically

Tags: xslt

What is the most basic syntax in XSLT to declare a global variable for a string of text and then reference that text value into the attributes you are going to output later on the XSLT?  Sounds simple - but has a specific syntax.

Answer (score 0):

After two similar questions were missing the tiny detail that makes this work, I thought it might be useful to share this.  Answer:

Variable declaration (near beginning of the XSL):

```
<xsl:variable name="defaultIconStyle" select="'Icon - Style'"/>
```

Note the single quotes inside the double quotes for the text string.

This method was also proposed but may be more resource/expensive:

```
<xsl:variable name="defaultIconStyle">Icon - Style</xsl:variable>
```

Calling this into an attribute value later: 
(in this case, to set a character style for a tag targeted for inDesign)

```
<xsl:template match="note-mytype">
    <xsl:copy><ph aid:cstyle="{$defaultIconStyle}"><image href="file:///myIcon.ai"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text></ph><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Some might say that `<xsl:variable name="defaultIconStyle">Icon - Style</xsl:variable>` is more "basic" (whatever that means).

Comment: @michael.hor257k Examples I looked at wrapped text in `xsl:text` tags inside the variable.  I did not realize you could do what you just did - so glad I started this thread on here.  Will add your input to the answer for completeness.

Comment: The version with a `select` attribute creates a string, which is what you want. The version without creates a result tree fragment (1.0) or document node (2.0+) which (a) is likely to be considerably more expensive (unless you're blessed with a good optimizer), and (b) can lead to surprises eg. if you use the variable in a boolean context.

Comment: Thanks!  That's useful.  Just edited answer to take that into account though your comments are more detailed.

Comment: "Different" does not necessarily mean "not recommended". In your example, the difference is negligible - and readability has its own advantages.

Comment: Note that with XSLT 2 and 3 to benefit from the better readability (or easier typability if you had nested quotes, for instance) of `<xsl:variable name="defaultIconStyle">Icon - Style</xsl:variable>` but to ensure you have a string value bound to the variable and not a result tree fragment or a document node you can use `<xsl:variable name="defaultIconStyle" as="xs:string">Icon - Style</xsl:variable>` with a suitable namespace declaration `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` in the stylesheet.